# Object indefinido ao ler do IndexedDB (JS)

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Estou usando IndexedDB para gravar uma tabela simples usando o JavaScript.
Ao selecionar um registro para alteração, o mesmo é lido e carregado no form. Porém, ao tentar atualizá-lo no banco o mesmo não é lido e retorna um objeto indefinido. Segue a função de Update que fiz:

```
function updtCliente(iID){ // <-- O código vem corretamente para a função
   var oStr = oDB.transaction(['clientes'], 'readwrite')
                 .objectStore('clientes');
   var rReq = oStr.get(iID);

   rReq.onerror = function(e){
      Mensagem('Não foi possível ler o registro.');
   };

   rReq.onsuccess = function(e){
      var dData = rReq.result; // <-- A variável "dData" fica "undefined"
      dData.cli_nome = $("#cli_nome").val();
      dData.cli_email = $("#cli_email").val();
      dData.cli_telefone = $("#cli_telefone").val();
      dData.cli_ativo = ($("input[name=cli_ativo]:checked").val() == 'ativo') ? '1' : '0';

      var rUpdt = oStr.put(dData);

      rUpdt.onerror = function(e){
         Mensagem('Erro na atualização.');
      };

      rUpdt.onsuccess = function(e){
         window.location.reload(false);
      };
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque:

```
var dData = rReq.result; // <-- A variável "dData" fica "undefined"
```

por

```
var dData = e.target.result;
```

Comment: Jorge, já fiz isso... já concatenei a leitura do registro com a função de sucesso mesmo assim não foi: 
    "oStr.get(iID).onsuccess = function(e){var dData = e.target.result; ...."

Comment: Tem a certeza que essa chave está base de dados

Comment: Está sim. Ao carregar o formulário que quero editar, ele traz os dados preenchidos com o ID junto. Ao usar o debug, eu vejo que os dados estão no banco. Mesmo passando com o debug, ao dar "onsuccess" a variável "e.target.result" fica "undefined". Eu uso esse mesmo comando para carregar os dados no formulário para alteração... Tá muito estranho isso...

Comment: Coloque o código que usa para carregar os dados do cliente e faça console.log(iID) para ter a certeza que está recebendo o chave certa

Comment: Jorge, achei! Ao passar pelo ".get(iID)" essa variável estava como string. Eu consegui resolver isso colocando ".get(parseInt(iID))". O ID no banco é auto-incremental e eu não percebia que estava passando string, já que ao carregar o form a variável vinha como integer. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vou marcar como resolvido.